# A Spring instantiated class via @Autowired - when referenced generates null pointer exemption

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Got the following Classes

```
       @Component
       @DependsOn({"classB"}
       public class ClassA{
       @Autowired ClassB classB;
        public ClassA(){
         log.info("Instantiating Class A") // 
        }

            executeA(){
             classB.executeB();  //null pointer
            }
        }

    @Configuration
    @Endpoint
    public class EndPointClass {
    @Autowired
    ClassA classA;
       webserviceEndpoint1() {
          classA.executeA(); // this line works fine without any errors
       }

    }

    @Service
    public class ClassB {

       public ClassB() {
         log.info("Instantiating Class B") // This line is executed before the Class A 
       }

      public void executeB() {
      }

    }
```

When I run the above I can see that ClassB gets instantiated by spring and also before Class A is instantiated but as soon it gets to classB.executeB I get a null pointer exception. This is all running in Springboot.

Any ideas on this please ?

Comment: Do you have these classes in the same package? Why `EndPointClass` class has `Configuration` annotation?

Comment: there are not in the same packages but all share the same base package entry. ie  com.basepackage.package1.ClassA                   com.basepackage.package2.ClassB.                                                                            The EndPoint class has the configuration because it's registering a couple of  beans   And to add that the EndPoint class has the @ComponentScan(basePackages  = {"com.basepackage"}) annotation And lastly the main class sits in com.basepackage.packageA.childpackage.Main

Comment: Could you please try to include explicit bean definitions for both ClassA and ClassB in your @Configuration? Using constructor injection would too be helpful.

Comment: tried it and pretty much the same result as above.. strange...

Comment: If I directly auto wire Class B into the configuration class (EndpointClass) it works ok.